# select count(*) with group_by in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, count, group-by

I have a library That generates a CRUD with pagination using mysql and created a query with group_by, but the **$ this-> db-> count_all_results ()** is not counted correctly.

I made an adjustment by changing the function of the CodeIgniter for an alternative, using the previous select

```
select count (*) from ('. $ this-> db-> _compile_select ().') x'
```

Anyone have other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must especify other params after the count_all() function.

Look this:

```
$this->db->group_by('my_table_col');
$total = $this->db->count_all('my_table');
```

Cleber.